# Type 'SideBar' does not conform to protocol 'SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am coding a sidebar and I have got this error

```
import UIKit


@objc protocol SideBarDelegate{
    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index:Int)
    optional func sideBarWillClose()
    optional func sideBarWillOpen()
}

class SideBar: NSObject, SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate {

    let barWidth:CGFloat = 150.0
    let sideBarTableViewTopInsert:CGFloat = 64.0
    let sidebarContainerView:UIView = UIView()
    let sideBarTableViewController:SideBarTableViewController = SideBarTableViewController()
    var originView:UIView! = nil

    var animator:UIDynamicAnimator!
    var delegate:SideBarDelegate?
    var isSideBarOpen:Bool = false

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>)
    {
      super.init()
        originView = sourceView
        sideBarTableViewController.tableData = menuItems

        setupSideBar()

        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: originView)

        let showGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        showGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(showGestureRecognizer)

        let hideGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        hideGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(hideGestureRecognizer)

    }

    func setupSideBar()


    {
        sidebarContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(-barWidth - 1, originView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, originView.frame.size.height)
        sidebarContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        sidebarContainerView.clipsToBounds = false

        originView.addSubview(sidebarContainerView)

        let blurView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
        blurView.frame = sidebarContainerView.bounds
        sidebarContainerView.addSubview(blurView)

        sideBarTableViewController.delegate = self
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.frame = sidebarContainerView.bounds
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.clipsToBounds = false
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.scrollsToTop = false
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(sideBarTableViewTopInsert, 0, 0, 0)

        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.reloadData()

        sidebarContainerView.addSubview(sideBarTableViewController.tableView)
    }


    func handleSwipe(recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)

    {
        if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        {
            showSideBar(false)
            delegate?.sideBarWillClose!()
        }
        else
        {
           showSideBar(true)
            delegate?.sideBarWillOpen!()
        }

        func showSideBar(shouldOpen:Bool)
        {

        }

    func sideBarControlDidSelectRow(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        delegate?.sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    {

    }
```

I got the error at the line

`class SideBar: NSObject, SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate {`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index:Int)`, since it is not optional.

Comment: If you just want to compile, provide an empty implementation for the function in your SideBar class -- like so: "func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index:Int) {}". I can't tell you exactly what you need to implement inside the function, that I'm afraid you need to code yourself.

Comment: Could you share the project? I can take a look.

Comment: @BenWelterveden I suggest you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: Yes, that is a good reading. Now regarding the problem you are having... Care to share the project?

Comment: If you want... Where should I upload my project?